# gernericservlet.config is not visible

Tags: javascript, jsp

Hi i am trying to get the folder path...

here is the code which i tried

```
String getPath= config.getServletContext().getRealPath("Config/test.xml").replaceAll("//", "////");
```

and also i tried with

```
String getPath= config.getServletContext().getRealPath("Config/test.xml");
```

it is saying the below error

The field genericServlet.config is not visible..

how to overcome this..any ideas...mostly appreciated..!!

Comment: Try using    String getPath =  getServletContext().getRealPath("Config/test.xml");

Comment: Or getServletContext().getRealPath("/Config/test.xml");